# DataGrid hover event on row

Tags: material-ui

I'm unable to find any good examples in documentation on how can I add an event which is triggered on mouse hover over a row in DataGrid, I also need access to that row cell data. From what I understand, I have to create a custom Row component and subscribe it to GridEventListener?. Anyone has done something similar? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example code in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-with-hover-delete-dsy8zz?file=/demo.js:516-524).

You can use the `componentProps` to call functions when the cursor is on top of the row. Here I am storing the code itself it `setValue` state as well as activates the `Popper` component. Clicking the `IconButton` component will lead to getting the `id` of the row.

Hope this helps.

```
  <DataGrid
    {...data}
    componentsProps={{
      row: {
        onMouseEnter: handlePopperOpen,
        onMouseLeave: handlePopperClose
      }
    }}
  />
  <Popper
    ref={popperRef}
    open={open}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    placement={"right"}
    transition
    onMouseLeave={() => setAnchorEl(null)}
  >
    {({ TransitionProps }) => (
      <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
        <IconButton
          component={Paper}
          elevation="5"
          sx={{ transform: "translateX(-60px)" }}
          color="error"
          size="small"
          onClick={() => console.log("delete: ", value.id)}
        >
          <DeleteIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Fade>
    )}
  </Popper>
```